# Is it dangerous to charge laptop from car batterry?

Tags: battery-charging, charging, usb-c, laptop, usb-pd

Can we use a laptop charging adapter without a car? Is it dangerous?

Example: 12v car battery -> automobile auxiliary power outlet(car cigarette lighter) -> car adapter DC-DC with PD 12v to 20v -> laptop with USB-c charging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see why not. The adapter doesn't know whether it's plugged into a car, as long as it gets 12-ish volts.

If anything, it's probably *better* for the adapter, because cars have some heavy loads (starter motors) that can create weird voltages (way too low *and* way too high) for everything else plugged in.

In fact, I have actually done something like this, with a 240V inverter.